# How to use js in django template?

Tags: javascript, django

I have problem with javascript in django. My 'Hello Wold' app called alert doesnt work in django templete. How to fix it?

profile.html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'scripts/profile/alert.js' %}">
<script src="scripts/profile/alert.js"></script>
```

cmd: Not Found: /home/profile/scripts/profile/alert.js

my folders

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QYAk.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'scripts/profile/alert.js' %}">
<script src="{% static 'scripts/profile/alert.js' %}"></script>
```